# angularjs ng-focus multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to highlight input fields when selected using ng-focus. I have looked at some examples but can't find one that works for me.

The issue is when I select one input field not only does that input get highlighted but both of them gets highlighted.

How can I accomplish this with individual results?

```
<label class="item item-input item-dark">
                <span class="input-label">Make</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="M1" ng-required ng-style="style" ng-focus="style={'background-color':'#387ef5'}" ng-blur="style={}">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-dark" >
                <span class="input-label">Model</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="M2" ng-required ng-style="style" ng-focus="style={'background-color':'#387ef5'}" ng-blur="style={}">
        </label>
```

Comment: It is because ng-style in both points to the same variable style.

Comment: I don't understand how that connects them, could you explain a little bit more in depth? @AbdulRehmanSayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/2o0mym3y/1/

It contains your style which actually updates a variable & hence both of them get the same value.

& the right way. to just use a focus (a pseudo-selector)& a normal style.

```
.stylea:focus {
  background-color:#387ef5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you once focus one of the both inputs, the `style` variable will be set. Since both inputs are using the `ngStyle` directive with the same variable ( `style`), both of them are getting this style. So you have to use different variables here.

But still I would recommend you to use CSS selectors here. Just give both of them a class like `input-focus` with:

```
.input-focus:focus{
    background-color:#387ef5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.foucsfun=function(){
   $scope.apply=true;
 
      }
       $scope.foucsRemfun=function(){
      $scope.apply=false   
    
      }
       });
```

```css
       .focusColor{
      background-color:#387ef5;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
<label class="item item-input item-dark">
                <span class="input-label">Make</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="M1" ng-required ng-style="style" ng-class="{'focusColor':apply}" ng-focus="foucsfun()" ng-blur="foucsRemfun()">
            </label>
            
  </body>
  </html>
```